# .NET Core 2.2 Expired Cookie doesn't redirect user to login page

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web app that has an issue where it doesn't redirect the user to the login page when the cookie expires. Typical behaviour would be if I left the web app idle until the cookie expired and then clicked on a link within the app, I would be pushed to the login page and be asked to re-authenticate

However, the current behaviour is that I am redirected to an Access Denied page and when I try to logout, it just redirects back to the access denied page again and I have to manually delete the cookies in the developer console then click on a link within the app for it to logout.

This is my cookie settings. I am unsure of if I have set it incorrectly?

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.Name = safeName;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    options.Cookie.Path = "/";
    options.Cookie.Domain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(AppOne.ClassLibrary.Globals.AOlobals.CookieDomain);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(CookieExpiryTimeSpanInMinutes));
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(CookieExpiryTimeSpanInMinutes));
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/Login");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

I use the [Authorize] filter on my controllers as well.

EDIT: I do not use sessions. Should I utilize it?